# Brackets in .Rmd code blocks

Tags: r

I am making some R markdown documents for my stats class.  I've noticed I get an error in some functions when I have a code block with {r}  instead of just r.  Like so...

````
``` r
this code will be fine
``` 

``` {r}
this code will have an error
```
````

When should I be using the brackets for codeblocks in .Rmd and when should I leave them out?

Answer (score 2):

Does it work without a space between the ```` ``` ```` and the `{r}`? It may be that the Rmd processor is getting confused about the spaces, but ignoring the bare `r`, and assuming the code is R by default.

The examples here don't have spaces:

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html

Comment: Thank you I believe you may be right.  I am having other problems with my code.